# SQL command not properly ended PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

From what I understand, this error is caused by clauses that are not allowed by the statements, but I don't see anything wrong with this query.

```
accept cruiseRange prompt "Enter cruising range: ";

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
   runSqlAndGetManyTuples (cruiseRange NUMBER)
  IS planeName varchar2(20); planeID NUMBER; averageSalary NUMBER;

  CURSOR myTuplesAreHereCursor IS
   SELECT Temp.pName, Temp.pID, Temp.avgSalary INTO planeName, planeID, averageSalary
   FROM (SELECT A.airplaneID AS pID, A.airplaneName AS pName, AVG(E.salary) AS avgSalary
          FROM cskresman.Airplane A, cskresman.Certified C, cskresman.Employees E
          WHERE A.airplaneID = C.airplaneID AND C.employeeID = E.employeeID AND A.cruisingRange > cruiseRange
          GROUP BY A.airplaneID, A.airplaneName) AS Temp;
```

Comment: You CREATE OR REPLACE a procedure. I see the declarations section - including an invalid AS before a table alias. The next, REQUIRED step in the procedure is to write the procedure **body** (including the BEGIN keyword and the END; command) - where are they? Without them, obviously "the command is not properly ended."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Never* use commas int he `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
2. The subquery is not necessary.
3. Oracle does not support `as` for table aliases.

You can write the query as:

```
SELECT A.airplaneID AS pID, A.airplaneName AS pName, AVG(E.salary) AS avgSalary
INTO planeName, planeID, averageSalary
FROM Airplane A JOIN
     Certified C
     ON A.airplaneID = C.airplaneID JOIN
     Employees E
     ON C.employeeID = E.employeeID 
WHERE A.cruisingRange > cruiseRange
GROUP BY A.airplaneID, A.airplaneName;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I'm just learning Oracle and my SQL is pretty shit right now but this clears a lot up.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `INTO` in cursor query and also you can not use the `AS` for table or sub-query alias.

Your cursor query should look like this:

```
CURSOR myTuplesAreHereCursor IS
   SELECT A.airplaneID AS pID, 
          A.airplaneName AS pName, 
          AVG(E.salary) AS avgSalary
    FROM cskresman.Airplane A, 
         cskresman.Certified C, 
         cskresman.Employees E
   WHERE A.airplaneID = C.airplaneID
     AND C.employeeID = E.employeeID 
     AND A.cruisingRange > cruiseRange
GROUP BY A.airplaneID, A.airplaneName;
```

**Suggestion:** Always use standard ANSI joins and sub-query is not required at all.